# how to set for system's timezone with mysql timezone?

Tags: c#, mysql, timezone, convert-tz

When I used for below function,

```
SELECT timediff( now() , convert_tz( now() , @@session.time_zone ,'+00:00')) ;
```

it shows `-07:00:00`

also the NOW() shows datetime different than my system's datetime.

also with   `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%time_zone%'` it shows,

```
Variable_name        Value 
system_time_zone     MST
time_zone            SYSTEM
```

How can I set for that, so that it does not conflict on insertion of entry in my database regarding date?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link to what you want:

http://support.modwest.com/content/6/256/en/how-do-i-change-mysql-timezone.html

Hope this helps.